# How can I get Bazel to include a JRE for a different architecture from the host computer?

Tags: java, bazel

I'd like to be able to cross-compile Java applications from my linux workstation to my Raspberry Pi using Bazel.

The fundamental problem I'm running into seems to be that the generated launch script references the java launcher that is in the runfiles directory and packages that binary up based on the host computer.

Simply setting --cpu to armeabi-v7a doesn't seem to have any effect, and even though I can get CROSSTOOLS to work with building C++ binaries using the Linaro tool chain, I can't find any documentation that would show me how to similarly substitutive the Java tools.

I spent some time fiddling around with the java_runtime, java_runtime_suite, and java_toolchain rules, but run into the problem that while I can set the java_toolchain, I can't seem to independently flex the host and target java architectures - just the versions.

If I modify the Java launcher script and hard-code JAVABIN to "/usr/bin/java" everything works (the example GPRC "greeter server" responds correctly), so I feel like I'm really not that far off of having a usable setup. I realize that I could supply a launcher that just passes everything through to /usr/bin/java, but I like the self-contained nature of Bazel builds and would prefer to work inside its structure.

So, what am I missing? What's the correct/expected approach for cross-compiling Java with Bazel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the --javabase argument to specify the JVM used for the target configuration (Raspberry Pi) and the --host_javabase argument to specify the JVM to be used during the build.

If you point --javabase to a java_runtime rule that tells where the JVM is found on the Raspberry PI, it should work.

Comment: Ha! I even thought to try calling --javabase on the result of the build, but I didn't think to call it on the bazel invocation. Thanks!